# How does navigation navigate function work?

Tags: react-native

I have been trying to use navigation.navigate() with parameters. but its giving me an infinite render.

```
 navigation.navigate(
  'EnterAmount', {
                   type: 'email',
                   walletAddress: data,
                   emailAddress: text,
                })
```

I tried using useEffect but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide some more code, as of where are you using this code?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you forgot the 2nt parameter of useEffect hooks?
The 2nd parameter holds by bracket.

```
useEffect(()=>{
}, [])
```